# Is it possible to measure software energy consumption with RAPL?

Tags: performance, energy, consumption

I've read about RAPL(Running Average Power Limit) in various different sites, but I'm still looking for an answer. I read that RAPL can measure the CPU energy consumption, or the entire system power consumption.

However, my question is: If I have a piece of code written in some language, such as MergeSort written in C, can I use RAPL to measure its energy consumption? Something like jRAPL is able to do, but not Java only. If yes, how can I do it?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a [post](https://luiscruz.github.io/2021/07/20/measuring-energy.html) on how to obtain energy measurements for different systems.
Some of the tools here are more fine-grained than others. Personally, I prefer using [Perf](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf.1.html) to collect energy measurements from a running application. Perf is also using the RAPL interface and it is convenient for command-line users but is limited to Linux distros. With Perf you can measure any type of executable in the following way:

```
sudo perf stat -r 5 -e power/energy-cores/,power/energy-ram. ./executable
```

The above will give you an output of the energy consumption of the executable (can be any program written in Java, C, Python, and whatsoever). The `-r 5` means that it will run the test 5 times to give you statistical results. However, this will give you the mean and not median results. Apart from the `energy-cores` and `energy-ram` you can get measurements from other components such as GPU baked on your processor.
Note that `sudo` is required because perf is collecting measurements from machine-specific registers found in Intel processors. If you want to avoid using `sudo` each time then run the following commands beforehand:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo -1 >/proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_paranoid'
sudo sysctl -w kernel.perf_event_paranoid=-1
```

Although you can use Perf to get energy measurements from many Linux distros, it is not supported for Raspbian (Raspberry Pi), yet.

Answer (score 1):

There is a recent project that allows that: [https://github.com/hubblo-org/scaphandre](https://github.com/hubblo-org/scaphandre/issues/25)

They also provide an example dashboard where processes and services consumption is isolated: https://metrics.hubblo.org